# Django installation problem on Windows

Tags: python, django, installation

I am trying to install Django on Windows XP. Here is what I did:

(1) Downloaded and installed Python 2.7 from

> http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7/python-2.7.msi

in C:\Python27

---

(2) Downloaded Django 1.2.1 from

> http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.2.1/tarball/

---

(3). After unzipping the file I placed Django's folder inside Python's site packages folder as below:

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.2.1

---

(4). Now when I try to run "setup.py" in Django folder, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.2.1\setup.py", line 48, in <module>
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Screenshot can be seen below:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you plan to use mysql, you're better off using python 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method

1. Install `easy_install` : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
2. Add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your system path
3. Open a command line and enter `easy_install django`.

This will pull the latest version of Django off the [PyPI website](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), and install it in that directory.

`easy_install` is definitely my favorite method for installing python modules.

Answer (score 1):

Delete C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.2.1

Unzip tarball anywhere you want, then copy "django" subfolder from unpacked tarball into c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\, and you're done. You don't need to run setup.py actually.

If you want to install using setup.py, then open your command shell (press Win+R, type "cmd" and press Enter), change into dir you unpacked archive to (e.g. c:\archive\Django-1.2.1), and run "C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install" without quotes.

Important note: you must run command shell with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate all-in-one open source Windows installer for Django that installs Apache, Python, etc.: [Djangostack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack)